# Can I build a French drain with old concrete and brick instead of rock?

Tags: sink, drain, drainage, french-drain

Can I use old pieces of concrete (broken up cinder block) and old brick instead of rocks in the construction of a French drain?

I'm thinking of building a French drain that leads to a dry well to drain a small kitchen sink I'll be adding to a backyard studio.

If these materials are OK to use instead of rock, I assume they should be broken up nearly as small as rocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These materiasl will work. Lining the trench with landscape fabric and wrapping it over the top (of the rubble) will keep silt from clogging your drain.  For higher volume flow, I'd add a perforated pipe at the bottom, but it's surely overkill for just a sink.

Definitely make your rubble somewhat uniform, for best support for the overburden (assuming you are burying the drain).

Comment: I agree. Make sure to wash them to get off any soil before you use them.